# Limiting Velodyne point cloud

Tags: ros, lidar, velodyne-pointcloud, velodyne

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The view_direction and view_width parameters updated for HDL32 doesn't seem to work. Has anyone tried it?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/229124/limiting-velodyne-point-cloud/) by [b-sriram](https://answers.ros.org/users/26278/b-sriram/) on ROS Answers with karma: 105 on 2016-03-15

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2016-03-18**:
Are you installing the binary driver packages, or building it yourself from source?

**Comment by [b-sriram](https://answers.ros.org/users/26278/b-sriram/) on 2016-03-22**:
I'm building them from source

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It works for me.

Run the driver in one terminal (with a PCAP or using the raw device):

```
roslaunch velodyne_pointcloud 32e_points.launch pcap:=~/Downloads/velodyne/32e.pcap
```

Run `rviz` in another.

In a third terminal run `rqt`.

- select Plugins>>Configuration>>Dynamic Reconfigure
- click on the `cloud_nodelet`
- set `view_width` to something less than 2*PI
- set `view_direction` to the desired angle (0 is straight ahead)

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2016-03-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0